# Very slow wireless connection (unrelated to power management) using  Netgear N150 WNA1100 in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I am using a [*Netgear N150 WNA1100 USB Adapter*](http://www.netgear.com/service-provider/products/wireless-adapters/wireless-n/WNA1100.aspx). The network driver is: ath9k_htc.

When I use Ubuntu 12.04 my wireless connection is much slower than when I use the WNA1100 with my Windows 7 installation on the same machine.

I have been researching this and the most common reason for this seems to be related to power management. However for me this is off by default.

I had entered a bunch of different commands and, at one stage, I got it to work at full power. But then I rebooted the machine and it went back to slow again.

After entering the different commands I was afraid that I may have messed something up, so I performed a fresh install of Ubuntu. I still have the same problem. My wireless connection is still much slower when using Ubuntu than when using Windows 7.

I am not sure what other info could help...

EDIT:

Ok, I have made live usb from the iso file I used to install Ubuntu on this pc, and ran it on my laptop. Still the same problem. However la[top works grand on cable.

I suppose this means that my wireless adapter or network driver can be eliminated as root of the problem..

So maybe to do with router itself? I use [ZyXEL P-660HW-D1](http://www.zyxel.com/uk/en/products_services/p_660hw_series.shtml)

Comment: degraded signal should not be a problem, cause it works perfect on my windows 7 installation on the same machine. Yes same problem after reinstalling. I only reinstalled just in case I messed something up while trying to repair :)

Comment: yes this is the exact one

Comment: try this link --- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1840001 --- it might be able to help.

Comment: no thats not problem. Althought reports only 1Mbps like described in that thread, when i had it fixed somehow it was exceeding that limit, so wouldnt have anything to do with that. As a matter of fact I only get like ~32Kpbs (max speed that mozilla showed when I attempted to download chrome.)

Comment: PS... MAybe look at it this way.. I did maybe 5-10 things that time I got fixed.. What could it possible have been that I done that would reverse to original state??

Comment: Maybe it's a driver issue. try this link --- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1447592&page=4 --- look at post 2, it's for 11.10, but it might work.

Comment: Also, you said power mgmt is off by default, but have you double checked? just curious.

Comment: i checked maybe 5 times.. as well was the first thing I did after fresh install, most definetely off by default.  ill check out that second link now.

Comment: Hm.. Ill try this tomorow, as it is late where I am and I need to reboot to Ubuntu before I even start lol Anyway, I dont think this will solve it. As it appears that they are talking about netgear n150 not actually working. Whereas mine works, just really slowly. Well anyway, find out in the morning. Thanks everyone for help so far!

Comment: I've never used it, but you could also try 'Windows Wireless Drivers' from software center.

Comment: @czifro no it looks like wireless driver not the problem, well not for the adapter anyway.

Comment: For your router, make sure the firmware is up-to-date.

Comment: @czifro Actually i found solution for this problem on another PC... But it doesnt work for my actual machine. this is the questio where i go into more detail [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/134456/slow-wireless-with-ath9k-htc-kernel-module)

Comment: Sorry i couldn't be of much help, i'm not very good with 'under the hood' stuff. maybe the new thread will bring about better answers.

Comment: Thanks anyway mate! I hope it does lol because I am seriously considering giving up Ubuntu, atleast till they make a f*** wifi to work out of the box

Answer (score 1):

Did you consult the following logs:

```
/var/log/pm-powersave.log
/var/log/syslog
/var/log/dmesg
```

?

Do you see any useful information in any of them?

What happens if you run this command:

```
sudo bash -x /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/wireless true
```

?